# Log complete call stack in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio Debug mode one can view the **partial call stack when reaching a given breakpoint**. I want to save and search the **complete** call stack during debug mode, without setting any special breakpoint. If and how is that possible? I am using Visual Studio 2019 Preview.

Comment: In what way is the call stack partial? Could you copy-paste it here? Also, what programming language is in question?

Answer (score 1):

For a .NET application, you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension to collect a complete function calls sequence. It works outside debug mode and without setting breakpoints.